# Capitalize the first letter after the first comma in every line from linux command line interface

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, regex

Given a file with lines similar to the following.

```
Mike,mackenna,mike.mackenna,mike.mackenna@123.com,yes,no,000
Joe,smith,joe.smith,joe.smith@123.com,yes,no,123
```

I would like to change the file so that the lines are shown as follows

```
Mike,Mackenna,mike.mackenna,mike.mackenna@123.com,yes,no,000
Joe,Smith,joe.smith,joe.smith@123.com,yes,no,123
```

Ideally I would like to make the change in vim using substitution and regex but I am also open to other possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very straightforward vim command:

```
:%s/,./\U&
```

The `\U` means *convert the following to uppercase*, and the `&` means the entire matched text (same as `\0`)

Since we don't give the `/g` flag, this will only run on the first match. You could also do a normal command:

```
:%norm f,lvU
```

This is like typing `f,lvU` on every line manually: `f,` find a comma, `l` move to the right, `vU` convert to uppercase.

To do this as a bash command:

```
vim file.txt -c "%s/,./\U&" -c "wq"
```

or

```
vim file.txt -c "%norm f,lvU" -c "wq"
```